# How do you add keycloak user migration provider properly?

Tags: java, maven, authentication, gradle, keycloak

The problem that I have is I can't get the provide work properly my keycloak project.

#### The version of keycloak : 7.0.0

#### The version of keycloak-user-migration-provider is from this link: https://github.com/Smartling/keycloak-user-migration-provider

> From the README.md above, they create a file, and showed the install federation provider.

`standalone/configuration/keycloak-server.json` and they add this to the `keycloak-server.json`.

```
"providers": [
  "classpath:${jboss.server.config.dir}/providers/*",
  "module:net.smartling.provider.federation"
],
```

In the older version of the keycloak(1.7.0), I saw him use the keycloak-server.json. However, I am using 7.0.0 version, it is completely not adding new provider to my keycloak project.

I tried to put both providers object in to the standalone.xml

The path is of the configuration file is that: `keycloak-7.0.0/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml`

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:keycloak-server:1.1">
    <web-context>auth</web-context>
    <providers>
        <provider>classpath:${jboss.home.dir}/providers/*</provider>
        <provider>classpath:${jboss.server.config.dir}/providers/*</provider>
        <provider>module:net.smartling.provider.federation</provider>
    </providers>

...
```

Once you add those to your standalone.xml, run the keycloak `./bin/standalone.xml` and it has no error, but I can't find the
`keycloak-user-migration-provider`. see the image[image]

I had also tried to put the module after the extension, but unfortunately, it is not working at all again. I am not sure it is the right place to put the code.

```
<extensions>
    <extension module="net.smartling.provider.federation"/>
</extensions>
```

Comment: HI. Did you try to register it as module as described in 6.2.2 in [keycloak providers](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_providers)? It also supposed to be deployed automaticaly if you follow 6.2.1.  I haven't tried it myself. Just started

Comment: I am not sure why the module does not setup correctly. I put the correct configuration for sure. maybe it is the version issue

Comment: I have some progress. Look at 11.5. I've added meta-inf file with class name and copied my jar into deployments like in 6.2.1. It started to load and crashed. Probably have to use jdk8 and I used 11. Will continue on Tuesday, will update if will get any success.

Comment: Yeah, I got the same crash as well. I have been tried to figure it out for 2 weeks. I finally end up of using Auth0. I also use the jdk8 for that project. Just update when you figure it out

Answer (score 2):

I have some progress. It is inconvenient to write in comments so I am putting this as answer.

According to [keycloak docs storage provder](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#userfederationprovider-vs-userstorageprovider) they no longer support UserFedarationProvider. They still have it in keycloak-server-spi package but it is just list of implemented interfaces.

So start from the simple.

I have created Provider implementing couple of interfaces

```
public class MyUserMigrationProvider implements UserStorageProvider, CredentialInputValidator, UserLookupProvider
```

and created my factory

```
public class MyUserMigrationFactory implements UserStorageProviderFactory<MyUserMigrationProvider> {
```

Have to implement getId method of the factory.

Than as described in 11.5.3 I've created

```
META-INF/services/org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageProviderFactory
```

file in my resources and added full name of my factory class into it.

Built jar and dropped it into `standalone/deployments` after restart keyclok has my provider.

To migrate user have to implement few provider methods

```
@Override
    public boolean isConfiguredFor(RealmModel realm, UserModel user, String credentialType) {
        logger.warn("isConfiguredFor");
        return credentialType.equals(CredentialModel.PASSWORD);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsCredentialType(String credentialType) {
        logger.warn("supportsCredentialType");
        return credentialType.equals(CredentialModel.PASSWORD);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(RealmModel realm, UserModel user, CredentialInput input) {
        logger.warn("isValid {} {}", user.getUsername(), input);
        if (!supportsCredentialType(input.getType()) || !(input instanceof UserCredentialModel))
            return false;

        UserCredentialModel cred = (UserCredentialModel)input;

        // pretend validating user password
        boolean isValid = cred.getValue().equals("123");


        // If the user is valid create user in local store
        if (isValid) {

            UserModel user= session.users().addUser(realm, user.getUsername());
            adminUser.setEnabled(true);

            UserCredentialModel usrCredModel = new UserCredentialModel();
            usrCredModel.setType(UserCredentialModel.PASSWORD);
            usrCredModel.setValue(cred.getValue());

            session.userCredentialManager().updateCredential(realm, user, usrCredModel);
            // add roles if needed
            // RoleModel adminRole = realm.getRole(AdminRoles.ADMIN);
            // user.grantRole(adminRole);

        }

        return isValid;
    }
```

I am not sure what you are planning to do in your provider. There are few different interfaces you need to implement for different things.

Look at 11.3 for interfaces examples and 11.13 for old UserFedarationProvider migrations.